# What is the maximum character for Custom data(key/value) in Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I know that the maximum characters for message text in Firebase Console is 1024chars but what about Custom data(key/value)? I tried to insert only about **250characters in to key/value**, and the UI is showing that it is invalid.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it on my Firebase Console and it seems the maximum number of characters (for the value) before the UI indicator turns red is 200 characters. Tried to look around and there isn't any documentation that explicitly mentions it though.

This is per each value. However, you still have to watch out for the size limit for data payloads (4KB).